# $ not defined, when trying to load jQuery on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider this script saved in script.js :

```
if ((typeof window.jQuery) == "undefined") {
    var js = document.createElement("script");
    var he = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    js.type = "text/javascript";
    js.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js";
    he.appendChild(js);
}


$('document').ready(function(){
    alert('testing');
});
```

Then a basic html page like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>

<script src=script.js></script>
```

This result in an error:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>   script.js
>   Line 8

Why is $ not defined? First comes the code between if, then the code `ready()`. This queues the code in the callback function to be called when the document is loaded right?

If I look at the code in Firebug, jQuery is properly loaded. Does this happen after `document.read` ? or is it something else I missed here?

Comment: Your script tag is _outside_ of the document. Insert it before the closing `body` tag

Comment: Also check how the HTML5 Boilerplate does it, maybe you're complicating things: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html. Or did I not understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: You're loading jQuery asynchronously, that's why.

Comment: That’s *how you load scripts asynchronously*. Just don’t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on loading scripts in this way, ask the browser to let you know when it's actually ready to use.

```
if (typeof jQuery !== "function") {
    var js = document.createElement("script");
    var he = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    js.type = "text/javascript";
    js.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js";
    he.appendChild(js);

    js.addEventListener("load", function () {
        alert(typeof $);  // function
    });
}

alert(typeof $); // undefined
```

<sub>Side note: it's usually better to strictly check types.  If `window.jQuery` is an object, number, or string, your code shouldn't be okay with that.</sub>